# Wait for all jenkins job (same job but different parameters) to complete to start next job

Tags: join, jenkins, build, parallel-processing

Here is what I'm trying to do in Jenkins.

```
                   Job A
           ----------------------
           |        |      ....  |
        Job B1    Job B2....    Job Bn
           |        |      ....  |
        Job C1    Job C2....    Job Cn
           |        |      ....  |
           ----------------------
                    |
                  Job D
```

Job B and Job C are called several times using different parameters. Once all Job C's are done, I would like to start Job D. I tried "Trigger Parametrized Build", Build Flow and Work Flow plugins. Though this can be easily achieved using Build Flow, it doesn't have restart failed jobs facility. Also tried "Matrix plugin" but problem is that log files are not consolidated which makes it very hard to use.

Thanks in advance
Saran

Comment: I ended up using Build Flow with command line options to control the flow

Answer (score 0):

There must be a plugin out there to make this happen. Google is your friend.

But till then here is a hack to do this.

1 -Let very Job C create a file in common folder available to all the other instances of Job C.
Make sure that the file name has some unique id so that Job can recognize which file it created.

2-At the end of the Job, Job deletes the file it created.

3- Job checks if the folder where the file was created is empty. If yes then trigger job D. Else do nothing.